# Is there a way for my ally to cast "target: you" spells on me?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, targeting

Many useful buff spells have "target you". Is there a way to have them target someone else (via a metamagic or something)?

Yes I'm aware that I can target my familiar with such spells. That's not very useful. Instead I'd like to give my familiar or other companion a wand with such spell and have it target me.

Comment: I've edited the title of the question since originally it was much broader than the question you're actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

[Share Spells](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Share%20Spells) is designed exactly for this.

> You can cast a spell with a target of “you” on an ally as a touch spell, as per the share spells familiar ability, so long as the ally possesses the Bonded Mind feat.

So if the caster has [Share Spells](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Share%20Spells) and the ally has [Bonded Mind](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Bonded%20Mind), the caster may cast spells with a target of "you" onto the ally.

---

The prerequisites for Share Spells do limit the number of casters who can take it easily though, so keep that in mind.

> Bonded Mind, ability to share spells with an animal companion, eidolon, familiar, or phantom, caster level 1st.

Comment: It doesn’t seem as though a familiar could qualify for this feat.

Comment: Ah Yup, I missed that detail in the post (since I was going off of the original title), still, it's useful information so I'll leave it up.

Comment: Summoners get this for free with their Eidolon, FYI!

Comment: Hmm... what if I take these two feats and create a Simulacrum of myself? Could that Simulacrum use "target you" wands on me?

Comment: That would work @enumag just beware of the nebulousness of what's appropriate for simulacrums to have at their HD.

Comment: Actually it wouldn't work. Using a wand apparently doesn't count as casting a spell for the purpose of this feat.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

If the spell in question is 6th level or lower (or if you forward-port *Lords of Madness*'s 9th level version) and includes (or can [be modified](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/umbral-spell-metamagic/) to include) some harmful component, *Greater Glyph of Warding* can do the trick.  This particularly useful for *barkskin*, *iron body* (with spell level lowering abilities or *Lords of Madness*), and the like, which can legitimately be used for offensive purposes when forced onto an opponent, but can also be used to buff allies on the side.

If the spell in question is on the Alchemist list, it can be made as an extract and thus used to affect other allies via [shenanigans](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pvbo?Question-of-Alchemist-Infusion-with-Personal).

If the spell in question is *really* low level, you can give it to others via *Imbue with Spell Ability*, though if what you want is for someone else to take the *action* to produce the spell effect but that *effect* to end up on you, that won't work, of course.

*Magic Jar* sort-of lets you swap buffs, by swapping bodies instead.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: The Glyph of Warding-Trick won‘t work, I‘m afraid. Personal spells usually aren‘t harmful and the Toxic Spell Feat can only applied to spells _"whose effects can be negated by a successful Fortitude save“_. But spells with „target you“ don‘t have a saving throw ...

Comment: @PeregrinTookn That's addressed in the answer, is it not?  *barkskin* is harmful, *iron body* is harmful, *beast shape ii+* is harmful (and, arguably, any spell with the (polymorph) subschool).  Many personal spells are harmful. And that's already assuming the worst-case-scenario that harmful is taken to mean something other than 'not harmless'.  And Toxic Spell is an example of how you might modify a spell that isn't harmful to become harmful, not a guaranteed 'always available' way to do that.

Comment: I swapped the toxic link for umbral since the only target:you spells with saves either can already target other creatures secondarily or only allow Reflex or Will saves as far as I can find.

Comment: Is this https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/barkskin/ ?  How is it harmful, exactly?